# Spring-data with specification and sort property

Tags: spring-boot, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have two entitis, repositories and class implements Specification:

```
@Entity
    public class Person {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "phone_id")
        private Phone phone;

@Entity
public class Phone {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String number;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

public interface PersonRepositories extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Person> {
}

public class PersonSpecification implements Specification<Person> {

    private String name;
    public PersonSpecification(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
         List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if(name!=null) {
            predicates.add(builder.like(root.get("name"), name));
        }
        query.groupBy(root.get("id"));
        return  builder.and((predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
    }



  @Service
    public class PersonSearchServicesImpl implements PersonSearchServices {
        @Autowired
        PersonRepositories personRepositories;
        @Override
        public List<Person> searchPerson(String name, String order) {
            PersonSpecification person = new PersonSpecification(name);
            Direction direction = Sort.Direction.ASC;
            String[] sortProp = {order};
            Sort sort = new Sort(direction, sortProp);
            Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 10, sort);

            Page<Person> findAll = personRepositories.findAll(person, pageable);
        return findAll.getContent();
    }
```

some sample data:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringOrmSpecApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    PersonSearchServices services;
    @Autowired
    PhoneRepositories phoneRepositories;
    @Autowired
    PersonRepositories personRepositories;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringOrmSpecApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        Phone phone = new Phone();
        phone.setNumber("AAA");
        phoneRepositories.save(phone);

        Phone phone2 = new Phone();
        phone2.setNumber("BBB");
        phoneRepositories.save(phone2);

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("Barry");
        person.setPhone(phone);
        personRepositories.save(person);

        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.setName("Alfred");
        person2.setPhone(phone2);
        personRepositories.save(person2);

        Person person3 = new Person();
        person3.setName("Alfred");
        person3.setPhone(phone);
        personRepositories.save(person3);

        search();
    }
public void search(){
        List<Person> searchPerson = services.searchPerson("Alfred", "phone");
        searchPerson.stream().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));
    }
```

On database H2 works well but in Postgres when searching for data from such parameters get an error:

```
ERROR: column "phone1_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this answer is weak, but I've had to solve this for Oracle (I don't actually understand why it works for h2) short answer, you have to do what it's asking, and add that field to a group by. This syntax is probably incomplete, and wrong.

```
 query.groupBy( root.get("phone").get("id") )
```

Comment: I also have not found a better solution.